# how to enable a button out of several buttons to link to another div box? Html Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Synopsis:

I am trying to create a web page hosting a quiz game.

In the game, they are five questions with options to choose from => (Four Buttons to be precise [Each button for a different option]).

In the html page, they are five div boxes with which [are aligned to the middle].

my aim to to enable that in each of the boxes, when the user click on 1 out of 4 buttons for a question it makes the active box (display : none) and the next div box (display : block)

hoping it not too confusing,  here is the code:

Html:

```
 <div class="box box1">
    <h1>Awesome Quiz</h1>
    <p>Trivia Time !!!</p>
    <button id="start">Start</button>
</div>
<div class="quest box2">
    <h2>Awesome Quiz</h2>
    <p>Who was the first President of the United States?</p>

    <p>George Washington</p>
    <button class="option option1">SELECT ANSWER</button>
    <p>Thomas Jefferson</p>
    <button class="option option2">SELECT ANSWER</button>
    <p>Thomas Edinson</p>
    <button class="option option3">SELECT ANSWER</button>
    <p>I don't Know</p>
    <button class="option option4">SELECT ANSWER</button>
    <div class="page">
        <p>Question 1 of 5</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="quest box3">
    <h2>Awesome Quiz</h2>
    <p>What is Queen Elizabeth II's surname?</p>

    <p>Jason</p>
    <button class="option option1">SELECT ANSWER</button>
    <p>Windsor</p>
    <button class="option option2">SELECT ANSWER</button>
    <p>Drakeford</p>
    <button class="option option3">SELECT ANSWER</button>
    <p>William</p>
    <button class="option option4">SELECT ANSWER</button>
    <div class="page">
        <p>Question 2 of 5</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="quest box4">
    <h2>Awesome Quiz</h2>
    <p>What is the largest country in the world?</p>

    <p>Russia</p>
    <button class="option option1">SELECT ANSWER</button>
    <p>Canada</p>
    <button class="option option2">SELECT ANSWER</button>
    <p>India</p>
    <button class="option option3">SELECT ANSWER</button>
    <p>South Africa</p>
    <button class="option option4">SELECT ANSWER</button>
    <div class="page">
        <p>Question 3 of 5</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
let start = document.querySelector('#start');
let intro = document.querySelector('.box1');
let quest = document.querySelector('.quest');
let box2 = document.querySelector('.box2');
let box3 = document.querySelector('.box3');
let box4 = document.querySelector('.box4');
let box5 = document.querySelector('.box5');
let box6 = document.querySelector('.box6');
let select1 = document.getElementsByClassName('box2 option');
let select2 = document.querySelector('.box3 .option');
let select3 = document.querySelector('.box4 .option');
let select4 = document.querySelector('.box5 .option');
let select5 = document.querySelector('.box6 .option');

start.addEventListener('click', function(){
    intro.style.display = 'none';
    box2.style.display = 'block';
})

select1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    box2.style.display = 'none';
    box3.style.display = 'block';
})

select2.addEventListener('click', function(){
    box3.style.display = 'none';
    box4.style.display = 'block';
})

select3.addEventListener('click', function(){
    box4.style.display = 'none';
    box5.style.display = 'block';
})

select4.addEventListener('click', function(){
    box5.style.display = 'none';
    box6.style.display = 'block';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to run by making 2 changes to your JavaScript:

https://replit.com/@SeanPlusPlus1/Simple-Quiz-Game-for-Caleb-Stack-Overflow?v=1

I added the 2 comments to the JS here:

```
let start = document.querySelector('#start');
let intro = document.querySelector('.box1');
let quest = document.querySelector('.quest');
let box2 = document.querySelector('.box2');
let box3 = document.querySelector('.box3');
let box4 = document.querySelector('.box4');
let box5 = document.querySelector('.box5');
let box6 = document.querySelector('.box6');
let select1 = document.querySelector('.box2 .option'); // using querySelector here too
let select2 = document.querySelector('.box3 .option');
let select3 = document.querySelector('.box4 .option');
let select4 = document.querySelector('.box5 .option');
let select5 = document.querySelector('.box6 .option');

start.addEventListener('click', function(){
    intro.style.display = 'none';
    box2.style.display = 'block';
})

select1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    box2.style.display = 'none';
    box3.style.display = 'block';
})

select2.addEventListener('click', function(){
    box3.style.display = 'none';
    box4.style.display = 'block';
})

select3.addEventListener('click', function(){
    box4.style.display = 'none';
    box5.style.display = 'block';
})

// Commenting this out because there is no .box5 element in the HTML

// select4.addEventListener('click', function(){
//     box5.style.display = 'none';
//     box6.style.display = 'block';
// })
```

One quick note though, `document.querySelector` returns the *first* element that matches, thus your game appears to have a bug in it; the show/hide functionality is only triggered when clicking on the first button option.

You should look into querySelectorAll:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Good luck! And great start to your web dev project!